# Unresolved reference to self for class function

Tags: python, django

Why is my IDE telling me that there is an `Unresolved reference to self` in the line:

```
-->  photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=self.upload_path)
```

Code:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=self.upload_path)
    upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def upload_path(self, filename):
        title = self.album.title
        if " " in title:
            title.replace(" ", "_")
        return os.path.join(title, filename)
```

This error doesn't show up when I put the `upload_path` function outside the class. However, I want the function inside the class to try to keep things neat.

No IDE error but I am not sure why.

```
def upload_path(self, filename):
    title = self.album.title
    if " " in title:
        title.replace(" ", "_")
    return os.path.join(title, filename)


class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Because `self` doesn't exist outside of the methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`self` can only be used inside class methods which define it as a parameter.

In this case, you need to treat the method as an unbound method (without giving the value for `self`), because Django itself will pass in the instance as the first parameter:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    def upload_path(self, filename):
        ....

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
```

Note that because you are using `upload_path` inside the class definition itself, the usage must come after the definition of `upload_path`.

**Edit:**

According to [this bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22436), there is a limitation in Django's migration system on Python 2.x, which will cause it not to work with the above code, even though the code itself is correct. You will have to put the function outside the class in order to use migrations.

[The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#serializing-values) states:

> If you are using Python 2, we recommend you move your methods for upload_to and similar arguments that accept callables (e.g. default) to live in the main module body, rather than the class body.

Comment: The IDE removed the error but I get this error now =/ :
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'upload_path'`

Comment: I see this was accepted, what did you have to do to fix that error?

Comment: @Liondancer You shouldn't get that error with the code in my answer. Maybe you have things in the wrong order.

Comment: This is the code with Traceback: http://dpaste.com/2WCS1G4 Maybe I should have noted I wanted to migrate this. Someone recommended: try to convert it into @classmethod... arguments should be upload_path(cls, instance, filename) and then you can fix your migration by writing upload_path=Photo.upload_path

Comment: @Liondancer Apparently this is a limitation of Django's migration system. Although the code above is correct Python, Django's migration system generates more code based on it which is wrong. In the bug report [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22436), they say you need to put the function outside the class like you had originally.